# How to find all positive integers $a,b,c,d$ with $a\le\ b\le c$ such that $a!+b!+c!=3^d$ ?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to find all positive integers $a,b,c,d$ with $a\le\ b\le c$ such that $a!+b!+c!=3^d$ ?

Comment: Show some of your working to get idea what you are upto.

Comment: @DevarshRuparelia: Nothing much actually ; only that $a!(1+b!/a!+c!/a!)=3^d$ where $b!/a! , c!/a!$ are integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X = a!+b!+c!$.

- $a = 1$, otherwise $2 | a! \land 2| b! \land 2| c! \implies 2 | X \implies X \ne 3^d$
- $b \le 2$, otherwise $X \equiv 1 + 0 + 0 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies X \ne 3^d$.
- If $b = 1$, then $1 \le c \le 2$, otherwise, $X \equiv 1 + 1 + 0 \equiv 2 \pmod 3
  \implies X \ne 3^d$.
- If $b = 2$, then $2 \le c \le 5$, otherwise $X \equiv 1 + 2 + 0 \equiv 3 \pmod 9$.
  Since $X > 3$ in this case, $X \ne 3^d$ once again.

Combine all these, there are only 6 candidates for $(a,b,c)$:

$$(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,2), (1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,2,5)$$

By brute force, one can check three of them are solutions:
$$(1,1,1) \leadsto X = 3,\quad (1,2,3) \leadsto X = 9\quad\text{ and }\quad (1,2,4) \leadsto X = 27$$

Comment: actually if $b=1$ , then $ c=1$ , otherwise $c \ge 2 \implies 2|c!=3^d-1!-1!=3^d-2 \implies 2|3^d$ impossible!

Comment: Can you please explain the 4 th case when b=2!!I can't understand that!!

Comment: @SanchayanDutta if $a = 1, b = 2$ but $c \ge 6$, then $6! | c! \implies 9 | c!$. Since $X = 3^d = a! +b! + c! \ge 3 + 6! \ge 9$, we have $d \ge 2 \implies X \equiv 0 \pmod 9$. However $a! + b! + c! \equiv a! + b! \equiv 3 \not\equiv 0 \pmod 9$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Reduce mod 2. If $a\geq 2$, then LHS is 0 mod 2, but RHS is 1 mod 2.

Comment: indeed , so $a=1$ ; hence either both $b,c$ odd or both even ...

Comment: @user123733 ...Which gives the second solution (up to order).

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: what second solution? I can only see that $b!$ divides $3^d-1$ so $d$ has to be much larger than $b$ if $b>4$ ... I can't see anything else ...

Comment: If $b\geqslant 3$ then $3|3^{d}-1$ so $b\in\{1,2\}$

Comment: @user123733 $1+2+24=?$. And there some clues in answers and comments, that your numbers are rather small.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\ge 5$ then $a!$, $b!$, and $c!$ all end with the digit zero, thus so does their sum. $3^d$ never ends in zero, so we are limited to $a<5$.

This at least gets us started.